# How to solve vtkAppendPolyData.h file not found in point cloud library?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have tried [pcl17](http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/) to build my source code.

When I rosmake it shows that vtkAppendPolyData.h not found.[(the full msg)](http://pastebin.com/NXCVRaYT)

```
    [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/impl/io.hpp:45:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/io.h:488,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/file_io.h:42,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:44,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:1:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/point_types.h:56:0: 警告： ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/impl/io.hpp:45:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/io.h:488,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/file_io.h:42,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:44,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:1:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/point_types.h:636:0: 警告： ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/visualization/common/common.h:40:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:50,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:10:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/visualization/vtk.h:51:31: 嚴重錯誤： vtkAppendPolyData.h：沒有此一檔案或目錄
    編譯插斷。
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Is the VTK library among the compiler include paths?

You may also want to check that the libvtk5-dev package is installed, as discussed [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/vtk-header-files-missed-using-ros-pcl-visualization-under-ubuntu-11-04-td3038682.html).

Comment: I have already installed libvtk5-dev. I try to use libvtk-* to install but nothing new to be installed. What to do next? Thank you~

Comment: I found that I should change src from include <*> to include <vtk-5.8/*>. How to prevent changing source code? Thank you~